# Unable to find devnet logs for errored programs with Java client

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, failed, java

I am unable to find logs of failed solana program invocation (on devnet) when I invoke the program with Java solana client([this solanaj library](https://github.com/paymennt/solanaj)). However, when I invoke the same program using @solana/web3.js - then I am able to find logs of failed program invocations on devnet.

For instance - [this](https://explorer.solana.com/address/8TJ5r27ecNTQxiLf3ur3fkC6SJU28WL4REYX89GQSAyu?cluster=devnet) is a simple solana program that I wrote that simply returns error.

In the [transaction history section of the onchain program](https://explorer.solana.com/address/8TJ5r27ecNTQxiLf3ur3fkC6SJU28WL4REYX89GQSAyu?cluster=devnet), you can find failed results with logged error. However, when I invoke the same program with java client ([this solanaj library](https://github.com/paymennt/solanaj)), I don't see the failed result on the devnet explorer, however I do get a failed error response in the java program.

Web3 program invocation code is as follows:

```
let txid = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, tx, signers, {
skipPreflight: true,
preflightCommitment: "confirmed",
commitment: "confirmed",
});
```

Java program invocation code is as follows:

```
final String transactionId = rpcClient.getApi().sendTransaction(transaction);
```

I suspect that this could be because web3 invokes sendAndConfirmTransaction where as java client invokes sendTransaction. There is no support in the java client to invoke sendAndConfirmTransaction.
Another suspicion I have is on additional parameters namely skipPreflight, preflightCommitment, commitment that I can pass through web3 client but there is no such support in the java client library.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Could be that the Java client is not skipping Preflight, aka. Transaction simulation, which means that if you have a transaction that automatically fails, the client won't even send the transaction.

Comment: I am writing a custom java client to vet this out now. I will update the thread. Thanks!